# Node Gallery Lightbox

Tags: javascript, media

I am using [Node Gallery](https://drupal.org/project/node_gallery) Module, just want to know if there is a way we can open the images in Lightbox or Colorbox? I know this can be done in [Media Gallery](https://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) module but can not find any way in Node Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done quite easily. I'm assuming that you are using Drupal 7 and using the Node Gallery as well as the Node Gallery API.

- Install [Colorbox for Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) (including the library - follow the instructions on that page).
- Now you have to some editing of the site structure (exact paths may vary but the provided paths will work if you are using the default Node Gallery installation settings):
- go to `admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display` (or browse: Admin->Structure->FileTypes->Image [Manage File Display]). Select `Node Gallery File Thumbnail` and put a check before `Colorbox`. Scroll down to Display Settings and under Content Image Style select `node_gallery_thumbnail` and select `Per page gallery` in the Gallery (image grouping) dropdown. Then Save Configuration.

Slightly complicated but not horribly so.